# Which is better? Unit-test project per solution or per project?

Tags: unit-testing, nunit, xunit.net

Is it better to have a unit-test project per solution or a unit-test project per project?

With per solution, if you have 5 projects in the solution you end-up with 1 unit-test project containing tests for each of the 5 projects.

With per project, if you have 5 projects in the solution you end-up with 5 unit-test projects.

What is the *right* way?

*I think it's not the same question as [Write Unit tests into an assembly or in a separate assembly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/271808/write-unit-tests-into-an-assembly-or-in-a-separate-assembly)*

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Assemblies are a packaging/deployment concern, so we usually split them out because we don't want to deploy them with our product. Whether you split them out per library or per solution there are merits to both.

Ultimately, you want tests to be immediately available to all developers, so that developers know where to find them when needed. You also want an obstacle free environment with minimal overhead to writing new tests so that you aren't arming the cynics who don't want to write tests. Tests must also compile and execute quickly - project structure can play a part in all of this.

You may also want to consider that different levels of testing are possible, such as tests for unit, integration or UI automation. Segregating these types of tests is possible in some tools by using test categories, but sometimes it's easier for execution or reporting if they are separate libraries.

If you have special packaging considerations such as a modular application where modules should not be aware of one another, your test projects should also reflect this.

In small projects where there aren't a lot of projects, a 1:1 ratio is usually the preferred approach. However, Visual Studio performance quickly degrades as the number of projects increases. Around the 40 project mark compilation becomes an obstacle to compiling and running the tests, so larger projects may benefit from consolidating test projects.

I tend to prefer a pragmatic approach so that complexity is appropriate to the problem.  Typically, an application will be comprised of several layers where each layer may have multiple projects.  I like to start with a single test library per layer and I mimic the solution structure using folders. Divide when complexity warrants it. If you design your test projects for flexibility then changeover is usually painless.

Comment: Being pragmatic generally leads to an acceptable approach. It perfectly fits here. Thank you!

Comment: I guess my point is there's no definitive better approach because the answer depends on your needs. Just be consistent.

Comment: +1 for "larger projects may benefit from consolidating test projects."

Comment: @ImrePühvel -- likely. Despite improved CPUs and SSD hard-drives since I answered this question, most projects will likely compile sequentially due to the dependency chain. Eight years ago, the performance overhead of copying files between projects over and over was painfully obvious. While this aspect may have lessened, I suspect you'd still find compiling 40 projects takes longer than compiling 10 and discovery and running fewer test libraries is likely faster too. The guidance still stands -- don't willingly take on complexity until it's necessary.

Answer (score 10):

I would say a separate project for each unit test project rather than in one project per solution. I think this is better because it will save you a lot of hassle if you decide to take a particular project out of a solution and move it to another solution.

Comment: If you are worried about too many projects in your solution 'cluttering it up', you can add all the tests to a separate solution folder.

Comment: @aceinthehole, solution folder doesn't help with Visual Studio performance degradation when  number of projects grows, as it was mentioned by bryanbcook

Comment: I would definitely go this way. like MyApp.ClassLibrary,  MyApp.ClassLibrary.UnitTests, MyApp.ClassLibrary.IntegrationTests

Answer (score 4):

We have one to one ratio from file to projects of solution in a very large system, we have reached a point where build takes more than 90 mins every time we check-in. I have  created new solution configuration which builds only test projects, new configuration runs once a days to make sure all test cases are working ,developers can switch to unittest config to test their code in their development environment. Pl. let me know your feed back

Answer (score 3):

I am going with one of those "it depends" answers.  Personally, I tend to put all of the tests in a single project, with separate folders within the project for each assembly (plus further sub-folders as necessary.)  This makes it easy to run the entire set, either from within VisualStudio or CruiseControl.net.

If you have thousands of tests, a single project might prove too difficult to maintain. Also, as Peter Kelly mentioned in his response, being able to easily split the tests if you move a project can be useful.

Answer (score 2):

Personally I write one test assembly per project. I then create one nunit project per solution and reference all of the relevant test assemblies from that. This reflects the organisation of the projects and means that if projects are reused in different solutions then only the relevant unit tests need to be run.