# NUnit project structure

Tags: wpf, nunit

I have some question regarding the NUnit test project and very new with NUnit.

1. For every wpf project there should be a test project or a single test project for a solution?
2. The test project will be class library project?

Thanks in advance. I am waiting for your quick response

Answer (score 2):

Your first question is addressed here already: [Which is better? Unit-test project per solution or per project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5197192/which-is-better-unit-test-project-per-solution-or-per-project)  In a nutshell, there's no hard and fast rule, just be consistent and when possible try to mimic how you expect your libraries to be used.

For your second question, yes, it should be a library.  It won't have anything other unit tests -- which are just classes with methods -- so there's no reason to make it an application or any other type of project.